# removing .html with .htaccess gives 404 error

Tags: html, .htaccess, ftp

So I just figured out how to make my own custom 404 page and the 404 page works now. 
I did all the .htaccess stuff for 404 page but now I am trying to remove the .html from the url.
I put in the code i found from the internet and i belive it worked, because now the .html is gone but i am getting a 404 error page. e.x domain.com/contact shows me my 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /error_404.html

ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html

RemoveType x-mapp-php4 .html


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The bottom part where "RewriteCond" starts is the code for the removal of .html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
 RewriteRule .* $0.html
 RewriteRule (.*) /error_404.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: nope, it just makes it worse ahahhahaha now everything i click on leads to a 404 page that is not even mine...

Comment: Yes, plus I have added few more things.

Comment: RemoveType x-mapp-php4 .html - this won't be needed

Comment: This one will still load your error page for errors and even load htmls without .html extension.